# Im getting --skip-grant-table in mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Im getting this message whenever I try to perform a query in mysql:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

How can I disable --skip-grant-tables?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you start mysql?

Comment: `service mysql start`

Comment: Did you execute `mysql_initdb -D [your-data-directory]`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I went on:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Thanks!